# R table function

Tags: r

If I have a vector `numbers <- c(1,1,2,4,2,2,2,2,5,4,4,4)`, and I use 'table(numbers)', I get

```
names   1    2    4    5
counts  2    5    4    1
```

What if I want it to include 3 also or generally, all numbers from `1:max(numbers)` even if they are not represented in numbers. Thus, how would I generate an output as such:

```
names   1   2   3   4   5
counts  2   5   0   4   1
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want R to add up numbers that aren't there, you should create a factor and explicitly set the levels. `table` will return a count for each level.

```
table(factor(numbers, levels=1:max(numbers)))
# 1 2 3 4 5 
# 2 5 0 4 1
```

Comment: +1, but I think it should be `levels=min(numbers):max(numbers)` so it can handle zeros and negative numbers.

Comment: @BondedDust Just doing what the OP asked. But yes, that would be more flexible.

Answer (score 1):

For this particular example (positive integers), `tabulate` would also work:

```
numbers <- c(1,1,2,4,2,2,2,2,5,4,4,4)
tabulate(numbers)
# [1] 2 5 0 4 1
```